# Error handler package

Tags: php, error-handling, composer-php, package

I would like to add a powerful error handler library to the project I'm currently working on rather then writing my own error handler functions.

My question is:

- Is it possible to use Yii2 error handler package independently, if so - which one does it use?
- If not, then what are some good industry-standard packages I can use with composer that have good support and offer all important functionality? Preferably with less dependencies.

Comment: Yii2 error handler is tightly coupled with rest of the framework and standard application flow, it is rather bad idea of using it in non-Yii application.

Comment: @rob006 yeah... that's what I thought. But what are some well known alternatives for an equally powerful error handler packages?

Answer (score 1):

After a few more hours of googling I was able to find two good libraries that do exactly what I wanted in my original question.

These are:

- [filp/whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops)
- [nette/tracy](https://github.com/nette/tracy)